# How to remove backslash from all columns in a Spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I remove all `\` characters that are a part of strings from multiple columns in a spark DF?

Sample row:

```
11~ADX\|0.00\|ZZ\|BP\|WHT~SE\|41\|0064~GE\|0001\
```

Expected output:

```
11~ADX|0.00|ZZ|BP|WHT~SE|41|0064~GE|0001
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `foldLeft` on all columns in the dataframe, in this way you can use `regexp_replace` on each separate column and return the final dataframe. Using the example dataframe in the question (called `df` below), to **remove all backslashes**:

```
val df2 = df.columns.foldLeft(df)((df, c) => df.withColumn(c, regexp_replace(col(c), "\\\\", "")))
```

You could also **escape all backslashes** with the following:

```
val df2 = df.columns.foldLeft(df)((df, c) => df.withColumn(c, regexp_replace(col(c), "\\\\", "\\\\\\\\")))
```

---

If not all columns should be used, create a separate variable containing the columns to use. To use all all columns except one (column `col` below) use:

```
val cols = df.columns diff List("col")
cols.foldLeft ...
```