# How to remove extra Escape characters from a text column in spark dataframe

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

My Data in a json looks like -

```
{"text": "\"I have recently taken out a 12 month mobile phone contract with Virgin but despite two calls to customer help I still am getting a message on my phone indicating \\\"No Service\\\" although intermittently I do get connected.\"", "created_at": "\"2018-08-27 16:58:30\"", "service_id": "51870", "category_id": "249"}
```

I read this JSON Using -

```
val complaintsSourceRaw = spark.read.json("file:///complaints.jsonl")
```

When i read the data in dataframe, it looks like

```
|249        |"2018-08-27 16:58:30"|51870     |"I have recently taken out a 12 month mobile phone contract with Virgin but despite two calls to customer help I still am getting a message on my phone indicating **\"No Service\"** although intermittently I do get connected."
```

Issue is

```
 **\"No Service\"**  need to be like  **"No Service"**
```

How i am trying -

```
complaintsSourceRaw.withColumn("text_cleaned", functions.regexp_replace(complaintsSourceRaw.col("text"), "\", ""));
```

However \ character excapes my " and code breaks. Any idea how to acieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove backslash from all columns in a Spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714318/how-to-remove-backslash-from-all-columns-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the "\" character, so in your regexp_replace you should look for two backslash ("\\") characters, not one.